# Url parameter going to 404 not found

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, query, parameter

I am trying to get data from url query in my woocommerce website. But when I go to the link it redirects to 404 not found. 
If I remove the 'product' from the query and add something else it works fine. I googled a lot but had no luck. 
Any idea why it's not working with product parameter?

```
https://mysiteurl.com/custom-page/?product[variant_id]=123&product[quantity]=1
```

Comment: Because `product` is a registered query var and when it exists in the URL query string, WordPress tries to look for a "product" post - e.g. `example.com/page-slug/?product=product-slug` - here WordPress will look for a "product" having the slug `product-slug`.

Comment: I need to add one or more products to cart and send them directly to checkout. All the data will be prepopulated from this URL https://mysiteurl.com/custom-page/?product[variant_id]=123&product[quantity]=1&sender[first_name]=John&sender[last_name]=Smith&sender[email]=john@smith.com&sender[phone]=80009001000
Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can use a different query var like `product2` or `add_to_cart`..